# mysql date xammp

Tags: php, sql, mysql, xampp

i've set a field as date in xammp server. but when i'm inserting a values, its saving like 0000-00-00.. i've even input it manually like 2010-10-10 but still saveing 000... is the problem with my code or the xammp server??? or is there any way to configure the date format in xammp???

$today = date('Y-m-d');

"/>

update.php
$date = $_GET['datee'];

$qry = "INSERT INTO course_detail(userid, course_id, hours_complete, week_no, date) VALUES('$member_id','$fname','$hour','$week', '$date')";
    $result = @mysql_query($qry);

Comment: You already asked this. As before, we need to see some code before we can tell if it's your code

Comment: It's probably a problem in OSI Layer 8.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably with your code. Have you quoted the date string when inserting?

```
INSERT INTO mytable SET datefield='2010-10-10'
```

Comment: i've assigned variable for date today and has set it to Y-m-d but still.. for some field i've used javascript calender, and even set the date format to 2010-10-10 since it was 2010/10/10 but still no improvement

Comment: You seem to be avoiding the question. Your answer has nothing to do with what I asked.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely not a XAMPP issue. I highly recommend you take a look at this link [MySQL Documentation on Datetime](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html)

MySQL Date has a fixed syntax and it generally falls along the lines of YYYY-MM-DD or YYYYMMDD. I'm sure you're using a presentation layer over MySQL such as *.NET (ASP,winforms), you can reformat the date generated by MySQL to match your locale. Here's how you do it on the Microsoft stack [MSDN Globalization Step-by-Step](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb688124.aspx), similar methods are available for whatever else technology you may be using.